# Multiple radio buttons selection

Tags: angular

I am working on an application where i use multiple radio buttons in a form control in a an angular form.
i would like to select multiple radio buttons.whenever the radio button is selected,
i would like to add the value of the radio button to an array when it is clicked before submitting the form.

Please guide me on how can i achieve this. thanks for the help.
HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="Form" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
 <div class="btn-group" ngbRadioGroup name="rb" formControlName="Name">
<input ngbButton type="radio" value="1">M1
<input ngbButton type="radio" value="2">M2
<input ngbButton type="radio" value="3">M3
<input ngbButton type="radio" value="4">M4
<input ngbButton type="radio" value="5">m5
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: This defeats the purpose of radio buttons. A radio button is defined as "...a graphical control element that allows the user to choose ONLY ONE of a predefined set of mutually exclusive options"

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use *ngFor to iterate the values?

Here's a material radio button [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/amnyrjoqxjy) but it's the same for normal html checkbox